# How to call methods within my abstract class that implements an imported interface?

Tags: java, interface, instance, abstract

Right now, I have a class 'Bag' that implements an imported interface 'USet'

My class 'Bag' is as follows:

```
package Bag;

import java.util.Iterator;


public class Bag implements USet<Integer>{

@Override
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean add(Integer x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public Integer remove(Integer x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Integer find(Integer x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Bag<Integer> myBag=new USet<Integer>();
}

}
```

I cannot call my class or access methods within it in my main. Simply put, I just want to add, remove integers in my Bag and create my own method of sorting them. However, since this is an abstract interface, it seems I cannot just call this. Is there a work around?

For reference, my imported USet is:

```
package Bag;

public interface USet<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    public int size();
    public boolean add(T x);
    public T remove(T x);
    public T find(T x);
    public void clear();
}
```

Comment: `Bag myBag = new Bag();`

Comment: @Blorgbeard Wow, didn't realize it was that simple considering USet is a generic and abstract interface. It was correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that does that. I believe it is quite simple so there is no need for an explanation.

```
package Bag;

import bag.USet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Bag implements USet<Integer> {

  @Override
  public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    System.out.println("iterator called.");
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    System.out.println("size called.");
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean add(Integer x) {
    System.out.println("add called with " + x);
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer remove(Integer x) {
    System.out.println("remove called with " + x);
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer find(Integer x) {
    System.out.println("find called with " + x);
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void clear() {
    System.out.println("clear called ");
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Bag myBag = new Bag();
    myBag.add(1);
    myBag.add(2);
    myBag.add(3);
    int size = myBag.size();
  }

}
```

[image: Test result]

**NB:** 
Looking at the code of your USet, I am thinking you intend to have special Set of Integers. If this is the case, then the code of your USet is not even a collection but a special Iterator. To make it be a collection you either extend the Collection interface, or Set specifically. In your case I believe its a Set you want. So your code should be like below.

package bag;

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public abstract class USet2 extends HashSet<Integer> {

}
```

and

```
package bag;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Bag2 extends USet2 {

  public Bag2() {
      super();
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
      return super.size();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
      return super.isEmpty();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean contains(Object o) {
      return super.contains(o);
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
      return super.iterator();
  }

  @Override
  public Object[] toArray() {
      return super.toArray();
  }

  @Override
  public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
      return super.toArray(a);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean add(Integer e) {
      return super.add(e);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean remove(Object o) {
      return super.remove(o);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
      return super.containsAll(c);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Integer> c) {
      return super.addAll(c);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
      return super.removeAll(c);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
      return super.retainAll(c);
  }

  @Override
  public void clear() {
      super.clear();
  }

}
```